# NPM can't find modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am building a Node app with express, and I'm running into some trouble when running node index.js from the command prompt.

I went into the directory with my index.js file and tried to run "node index.js" but it says that the controller module could not be found.

I have installed express, body-parser, and mongoose and they all show up in my node_modules folder.

In my Routes.js file, I have the following line of code:

```
var controller = require('../controllers/controller');
```

Also, doing:

```
var controller = require('./controllers/controller');
```

doesn't work either, so I am unsure if it is a problem with the custom controller directories or if it is a problem with how I am exporting my modules.

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '..\controllers\controller.js' when trying
>   to require a controller for my routes folder

If anyone could help me resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: And you do have a controllers folder with a controller.js?

Comment: Yes, my file paths are:

app
     controllers
          controller.js
     models
           model.js
     routes
            Routes.js
     index.js

Comment: `..` is parent directory, `.` is current directory, so you are indeed looking for parent directory if the require call is in `routes/Routes.js`. How are you exporting your modules? That should be `module.exports = <function>` or `module.exports = <object>` usually

Comment: could you edit your answer with the content of the controller file?